# Using groupby() on all columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am attempting to combine all rows in a DataFrame that share the same index, so that all data is put into a list for each column of the index.

### For example:

```
dict = {'ID': ['alpha', 'alpha', 'bravo', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'charlie'], 'Var1': [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5], 'Var2': [10, 10, 12, 13, 10, 11]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

df.set_index('ID')

         Var1  Var2
ID                 
alpha       1    10
alpha       2    10
bravo       3    12
bravo       3    13
charlie     5    10
charlie     5    11
```

The goal is to get:

```
           Var1      Var2
ID                       
alpha    [1, 2]  [10, 10]
bravo    [3, 3]  [12, 13]
charlie  [5, 5]  [10, 11]
```

---

**When I do what I thought was the obvious thing, It doesn't work as expected:**

```
new_df = df.groupby('ID')[df.columns].apply(list)

print(new_df)

ID
alpha      [Var1, Var2]
bravo      [Var1, Var2]
charlie    [Var1, Var2]
```

---

---

The only solution I could come up with is to iterate over each column and concat each result like so:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in df.columns:
    y = df.groupby('ID')[i].apply(list)
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, y], axis = 1)

print(new_df)

           Var1      Var2
ID                       
alpha    [1, 2]  [10, 10]
bravo    [3, 3]  [12, 13]
charlie  [5, 5]  [10, 11]
```

This seems like more than should be necessary for this, so I am wondering if there is a better way of performing the operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should using `agg`

```
df.groupby('ID')['Var1','Var2'].agg(lambda x : x.values.tolist())
Out[576]: 
           Var1      Var2
ID                       
alpha    [1, 2]  [10, 10]
bravo    [3, 3]  [12, 13]
charlie  [5, 5]  [10, 11]
```